# How do you initialize (through initializer lists) a multidimensional std::array in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to initialize a 2D std::array trough initializer lists however the compiler tells me that there are too many initializers.

e.g.:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> shape = { {1, 1},
                                            {1, 1} };
```

Compiler error: error: too many initializers for `‘std::array<std::array<int, 2ul>, 2ul>’`

But clearly there aren't too many. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to add one more pair `{}` to ensure we're initializing the internal C array.

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> shape = {{ {1, 1},
                                             {1, 1} }};
```

Or just drop all the brackets.

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> shape = { 1, 1,
                                            1, 1 };
```

Comment: It always feels like an abstraction leak to me that we have to do that. Just a result of the library not being "internal" to the language, but built _with_ it, I suppose.

Comment: Just tried this, if you want no warnings, `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> shape = {{ {{1, 1}}, {{1, 1}} }};`. eww

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest (without even have trying it, so I could be wrong)

```
typedef std::array<int, 2> row;
std::array<row,2> shape = { row {1,1}, row {1,1} };
```

Comment: It works however I'm wondering why my version does not. Both expressions seem equivalent on a first look.

Comment: @zoopp: No they don't. Basile uses an explicit construction, whereas you do not.