# Initializing a 2D vector using initialization list in C++11

Tags: c++11, stdvector

How can i initialize a 2D vector using an initialization list? 
for a normal vector doing :

```
vector<int> myvect {1,2,3,4};
```

would suffice. But for a 2D one doing :

```
vector<vector<int>> myvect{ {10,20,30,40},
                            {50,60,70,80}
                          };
```

What is a correct way of doing it?
And how can i iterate through it using for?

```
for(auto x: myvect)
{
    cout<<x[j++]<<endl;
}
```

this for only shows:
10,1 !

And by the way what does this mean ?

```
   vector<int> myvect[5] {1,2,3,4};
```

i saw it here and cant understand it! [Link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-4-initializer-lists-and-uniform-initialization/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you initialize (trough initializer lists) a multidimensional std::array in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504103/how-do-you-initialize-trough-initializer-lists-a-multidimensional-stdarray-i)

Comment: @trojanfoe AFAIK the answer to the first question is different between `array` (a POD) and `vector` (not a POD). The second and third question in the OP aren't covered in that answer, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is a correct way of doing it?

The way you showed is a possible way. You could also use:

```
vector<vector<int>> myvect = { {10,20,30,40},
                               {50,60,70,80} };

vector<vector<int>> myvect{ vector<int>{10,20,30,40},
                            vector<int>{50,60,70,80} };
```

The first one constructs a `std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>>` where the elements are directly initialized from the inner braced-initializer-lists. The second one explicitly constructs temporary vectors which then are moved into a `std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>>`. This will probably not make a difference, since that move can be elided.

In any way, the elements of the `std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>>` are copied back out into `myvect` (you cannot move out of a `std::initializer_list`).

---

> And how can i iterate through it using for?

You essentially have a *vector of vectors*,  therefore you need two loops:

```
for(vector<int> const& innerVec : myvect)
{
    for(int element : innerVec)
    {
        cout << element << ',';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I refrained from using `auto` to explicitly show the resulting types.

---

> And by the way what does this mean ?

This is probably a typo. As it stands, it's illegal. The declaration `vector<int> myvect[5];` declares an *array of 5 `vector<int>`*. The following list-initialization therefore needs to initialize the array, but the elements of this list are not implicitly convertible to `vector<int>` (there's a ctor that takes a `size_t`, but it's explicit).

That has already been pointed out [in the comments of that side](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-4-initializer-lists-and-uniform-initialization/comment-page-1/#comment-98012).

I guess the author wanted to write `std::vector<int> vArray = {3, 2, 7, 5, 8};`.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Thats really helpful specially the explict types that you used instead of auto , it makes things really clearer :)