# syntax of initialization of multidimensional std::array with initalizer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list, stdarray

The very straightforward question is: why does the following code not compile?

```
//foo.cpp
#include <array>
int main() {
  std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> a = {{0,1},{2,3}};
  return 0;
}
```

The error I get (gcc-4.9.2) is

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:4:55: error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<std::array<int, 2ul>, 2ul>’
     std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> a = {{0,1},{2,3}};
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504103/how-do-you-initialize-trough-initializer-lists-a-multidimensional-stdarray-i) addresses the same error but it does not ask for (and replies do not provide) an explanation why this syntax is not accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you initialize (trough initializer lists) a multidimensional std::array in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504103/how-do-you-initialize-trough-initializer-lists-a-multidimensional-stdarray-i)

Comment: that question addresses the same issue but only asks for the correct syntax. I'd like to know ''why'' this syntax (which would seem the most natural thing to do) does not work.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844475/why-cant-simple-initialize-with-braces-2d-stdarray

Comment: @George that's it thank you!

Comment: array is tricky because it sometimes needs extra `{}`. and how strictly depends on the compiler!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't simple initialize (with braces) 2D std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844475/why-cant-simple-initialize-with-braces-2d-stdarray)