# C++: array<> too many initializers

Tags: c++, initialization, stdarray, aggregate-initialization

The following code is returning the compilation error below.  I'm stuck understanding how there are too many initializers.  This code works using `vector<X>`.  Does anyone know why the error is being reported and how to resolve?  Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

struct X {
    int x, y;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    array<X,2> a0 = {{0,1}, {2,3}};

    for (auto& p : a0) {
        cout << p.x << endl;
        cout << p.y << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall test116.cc && ./a.out
test116.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test116.cc:11:34: error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<X, 2>’
     array<X,2> a0 = {{0,1}, {2,3}};
```

Comment: rule of thumb for `std::array`, if it doesn't work then add extra braces until it does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you initialize (through initializer lists) a multidimensional std::array in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504103/how-do-you-initialize-through-initializer-lists-a-multidimensional-stdarray)

Comment: My question was ans below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
array<X,2> a0 = {{{0,1}, {2,3}}};
```

Note the extra set of braces.

It seems a bit odd but it's this way because the only member of `array` is the actual array:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
class array {
    T val[N];
    // ...
};
```

The constructors are all implicitly defined so that `array` ends up being a trivially constructable type.

Comment: Why are the extra braces required?  Also note, I'm copying this nearly identical to Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 208, which shows no errata.

Comment: @notaorb Just added an edit. This constructor is implicit... If there were a manually-defined `std::initializer_list` constructor then they wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Sidenote: Brace elision works too: `array<X,2> a0 {0, 1, 2, 3};` (although I personally think that makes it hard to read).

Comment: Outer: initialiser for the array; middle: initialiser for the one member (the _actual_ array); inner: initialisers for the Xs. This is what happens when basic, fundamental features of the language are hacked in as user-defined types in the library

Comment: @notaorb the language standard for braced initialization keeps changing; it might have been correct at the time of publication!

Comment: The implicit construction is similar to `struct Z {int x[2];};` and `struct Z zz = {{0, 1}};`.

Comment: Tysm bro. u saved my assignment.

Answer (score 4):

You may use one of the following initializations because `std::array` is an aggregate that contains another aggregate as its data member.

```
array<X,2> a0 = { { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } } };
array<X,2> a0 = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
array<X,2> a0 = { { 0, 1, 2, 3 } };
array<X,2> a0 = { { 0, 1, { 2, 3 } } };
array<X,2> a0 = { { { 0, 1 }, 2, 3 } };
```

Comment: ... and they say C++ is strict :-) Both answers got my vote. Putting names to all the different initialization versions might provide some extra value.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my problem is related to the **version of g++**,**9.4.0** is ok and **5.4.0** not.**version of g++**.By the way, the version of g++ is associated with the system version generally.